# Angular 2+ Dragover Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I tried to fake the event the best I can using `dataTransfer` object on a dummy object.

```
el.triggerEventHandler('dragover', { dataTransfer: {} });
```

*It feels wrong but I had to give it a shot.*

Not being able to find an answer after hours of searching gives me the suspicion that this is a subset of something else I should already know. Any pointers on where to start reading would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Still could not find any documentation, I ended up doing the following:

```
el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('dragover', null));
```

It works fine, but I feel like I am missing something; wondering if this is the best method?

Comment: What are you testing here? can you add your test as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be the solution I was looking for:

```
el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('dragover', null));
```